# her office database has been compromised

Tags: word-meaning

What does **compromised** mean in this sentence from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmortem_%28novel%29)

> The leaks threaten Scarpetta's position, especially after she is forced to admit that her office database has been **compromised**.

**Compromise** means someone accept others requirements which is not the optimal choice(or some similar meanings) but it doesn't fit here in my opinion.

Comment: It means that the integrity of the database has been compromised. I.e., someone broke in and stole information contained in it.  [See here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compromise):  a. *To expose or make liable to danger, suspicion, or disrepute*

Comment: It is a very common term used in the field of cyber security. It means that the database has been successfully attacked by the attacker. The consequence of the attack could be information leak, integrity damage..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "compromise" has a few different meanings.  In this case, it is the security of the database that is compromised, meaning that the database has become vulnerable to outside interference.

> 3.1 -- Cause to become vulnerable or function less effectively.
>
> ‘yo-yo dieting can compromise your immune system’
>
> ‘last month's leak of source code will not compromise your IT security’
>
> -- *Oxford Dictionaries, [Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/compromise)*